# Boost filesystem linking issues

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to link Boost filesystem into my VS project. I built the boost libraries and when I include filesystem.hpp in my project I'm getting the following error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in App.obj  E:\SourceControl\zombiegame\ZombieGame\Projects\Windows\libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_58.lib(operations.obj)   ZombieGame
```

This is talking about the boost libraries having MD_DynamicRelease while my app has MT_StaticRelease. So I thought this was boost automatically linking for me since it's showing that it's using libboost_filesyste-vs12-mt-1_58.lib, but I think that's the shared version and I want to use the static version. So at the top before I include filesystem.hpp I added:

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_LIB
```

To stop boost from automatically adding the shared lib and then I added the static lib to the linker but it still acts like it's using the shared lib. What am I missing here?

Comment: The information which libs to link that comes from `#pragma comment(lib, ..)` directives is embedded into the ".obj" files, make sure you recompile all of them.

Comment: How does my project that I'm adding boost too know which one to use then? I'm confused. So I'm running b2 and passing parameters to it. What should I be passing as these parameters to get the right lib?

Comment: @user441521 Embedded in the .hpp files for Boost are lines like the following: `#  pragma comment(lib, BOOST_LIB_PREFIX BOOST_STRINGIZE(BOOST_LIB_NAME) "-" BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET BOOST_LIB_THREAD_OPT BOOST_LIB_RT_OPT "-" BOOST_LIB_VERSION ".lib")`  These are directives to help VS locate the proper .lib file. That particular line comes from `boost/config/auto_link.hpp`.

Comment: Right and by default it seems like boost wants to use dynamic library. I want to use static. So there must be some way to control that in the build process and some preprocessor in my project. When I just do a build specifying static linking then the project complains it can't find the shared lib so assuming by default the hpp file is looking for dynamic lib.